# According to git a commit is an ancestor of another commit but also not

Tags: git

So I have a weird case where some git log commands claim that a commit is an ancestor of another commit but other commands claim that it is not. Then after merging the commit again it is correct.

So it is definitely in the history:

```
> git log 533f43d27f1a937d43dc00cf33684efeeeea6f58 | grep 25303646749f814a64339845fef830d60236b47c
commit 25303646749f814a64339845fef830d60236b47c
> git log --oneline --graph 533f43d27f1a937d43dc00cf33684efeeeea6f58 | grep 253036467
| | * | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 25303646749 [commit message stripped]
```

But it is also not:

```
> git log 533f43d27f1a937d43dc00cf33684efeeeea6f58..25303646749f814a64339845fef830d60236b47c | grep commit
commit 25303646749f814a64339845fef830d60236b47c
> git log --oneline --graph 533f43d27f1a937d43dc00cf33684efeeeea6f58..c4353c35b7233c4cab8e63817aac28dda5dbf8bc | grep 25303646749
| * 25303646749 [commit message stripped]
```

I can't merge it:

```
((533f43d27f1...))> git merge 25303646749f814a64339845fef830d60236b47c
Already up to date.
```

But I can merge something else which contains it:

```
((533f43d27f1...))> git log --no-merges  ..c4353c35b7233c4cab8e63817aac28dda5dbf8bc | grep commit
commit 0f3704bf5a6428940ee0b1f1df36ebbe807cca99
commit 25303646749f814a64339845fef830d60236b47c
((533f43d27f1...))> git merge c4353c35b7233c4cab8e63817aac28dda5dbf8bc
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
```

And then it is not showing up anymore in git log:

```
((c474a8be528...))> git log ..25303646749f814a64339845fef830d60236b47c
((c474a8be528...))>
```

So far I have not been able to reproduce this with any other commit. Any ideas on what might cause this?

Comment: What version of Git are you running? If it's 2.28 or later, have you turned on some of the fancier new bitmap algorithms?

Comment: Do you have any active `git replace` on your repo ? from the root directory of your repo : run `ls .git/refs/replace`

Answer (score 0):

First :
You are using `grep` on the output of `git log`, which could also show you lines that appear anywhere.

Could it be that commit `533f43d27` (or one of its parents) contains a line stating :

```
commit 25303646749f814a64339845fef830d60236b47c
```

in its *message* ?

Second :
you inspect the history of `533f43d27`, but the commands in your question do not verify what is the value of the active commit (`HEAD`) :

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

---

To grep for commit ids : use `git rev-list` instead of `git log`.

To have a view of the history of your repo in your terminal, I recommend :

```
git log --oneline --graph

# can be combined with any other parameters for git log :
git log --oneline --graph 533f43d2
git log --oneline --graph 533f43d2..25303646
git log --oneline --graph --no-merges ..c4353c3
# etc ...
```

To set up a shortcut for it :

```
git config --global alias.lol 'log --oneline --graph'

# usage :
git lol 533f43d2..25303646
git lol --no-merges ..c4353c3
```

---

In your case, have a look at :

```
git lol 533f43d2 c4353c3
```

---

A command to check if `A` is an ancestor of `B` :

```
git merge-base A B
# if it displays A : A is an ancestor of B
# if it displays B : B is an ancestor of A
# if it displays something else : A and B forked, and aren't ancestors or descendants
```

Comment: The grep is pretty safe since "commit" can't appear at the start of the line if in a commit message, commit messages are always intended.

Comment: You're right. Do you have a clearer view using `--graph` though ?

Comment: --graph is practically useless since we have hundreds of developers contributing to several separate release branches via individual pull-requests and then the release branches get merged into each other. The graph immediately fills the whole screen... 

The commit can definitely be reached in the history via different routes. But so far I always assumed that `<commit a>..<commit b>` syntax is simply set behavior: Show me all commits that are ancestors of commit b but not commit a. But somehow I got git to violate that. So I'm trying to find out how that could work.

Comment: Added the output of some of the --graph commands in the question

Comment: Oh, you have one of those massive graphs to handle, ok. One point, in your "But it is also not" paragraph, the two ranges you inspect are different (`253...` vs `c43...`)